# Implementing Invisible reCAPTCHA with Redux Form

Tags: reactjs, recaptcha, redux-form

I am trying to implement [Invisible reCAPTCHA](https://developers.google.com/recaptcha/docs/invisible) with React and Redux Form. In general, the Invisible reCAPTCHA workflow is:

1. Render the "invisible" CAPTCHA, returning its widget ID.
2. Call `grecaptcha.execute` with the widget's ID. If necessary, the user will be prompted to solve a challenge. The result is passed to a callback function specified when the CAPTCHA was rendered.
3. Submit the form together with the CAPTCHA result.

I've created a React component intended to be used with Redux Form's `Field` that renders the CAPTCHA and updates the form state after `grecaptcha.execute` is called:

```
class ReCaptcha extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return <div ref={div => this.container=div} />
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    const { input: { onChange }, sitekey } = this.props
    grecaptcha.render(this.container, {
      sitekey,
      size: "invisible",
      callback: onChange
    })
  }
}
```

However, I don't know how or where to call `grecaptcha.execute` together with the widget ID upon form submission by the user. I cannot call it in `onSubmit` because the widget ID isn't accessible there. I could call it in `ReCaptcha` immediately after rendering the CAPTCHA, but if a user needs to solve the CAPTCHA he'll be prompted to do so as soon as the form has rendered.

This [minimal working example](https://gist.github.com/csmcanarney/2f3e740bf9d43e08062e427c69c96f6a) shows what I have achieved so far.

Answer (score 1):

Use the onSubmit prop to call grecaptcha.execute(), and point the data-callback to the 'real' onSubmit function.

```
let refToMyWidget;
const { handleSubmit } = this.props;

componentDidMount() {
  if (window.grecaptcha) {
    refToMyWidget = window.grecaptcha.render(this.container, {
      sitekey: "xxxx",
      size: "invisible",
      callback: handleSubmit(this.actuallySubmit)
    })
  }
}

preSubmit() {
  if(!window.grecaptcha) {
    return;
  }
  window.grecaptcha.execute(this.refToMyWidget)
}

actuallySubmit() {
  // submission logic here
}

render() {
  return (
    <form onSubmit={handleSubmit(this.preSubmit)}>
        <Field name="foo" component="input" />
        <button>Submit</button>
    </form>
  )
}
```

N.b. I haven't tested this code but it should be more or less right. If you run into trouble with loading grecaptcha into the page/form, I found [this](https://github.com/appleboy/react-recaptcha/blob/master/src/index.js) code very helpful.

Answer (score 1):

This way you can implement it anywhere in react

```
import React, { Component } from "react";

    export default class Test extends Component {

      componentWillMount = () => {
        const script = document.createElement("script");
        script.src = "https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api.js";
        script.async = true;
        script.defer = true;
        document.body.appendChild(script);

        window.addEventListener("load", this.onLoad);
      };

      onLoad = () => {
        if (window.grecaptcha) {
          window.grecaptcha.render("recaptcha", {
            sitekey: "",
            size: "invisible",
            callback: this.onCaptcheCompleted
          });
        }
      };
      onCaptcheCompleted = e => {
        //do what ever you want
        console.log(e);
      };

      render() {
        return (
          <div id="recaptcha">
            <input />
            <button onClick={() => window.grecaptcha.execute()} />
          </div>
        );
      }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I had to make invisible reCAPTCHA work for me because  the visible one is not responsive. [Here](https://developers.google.com/recaptcha/docs/invisible#example) is the example I implemented.

First thing to do is adding below tag to the body (or you can use [react-helmet](https://github.com/nfl/react-helmet)).

```
<script src="https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api.js?onload=onloadCallback&render=explicit" async defer></script>
```

Simplified version of my working code:

```
import React from 'react';

class YourComponent extends React.Component {
  componentDidMount() {
    // Create a script to make sure the reCAPTCHA API is called.
    const script = document.createElement('script');
    script.text = `
      var onloadCallback = function() {
        console.log('grecaptcha is ready');
      };
    `;
    document.body.appendChild(script);

    // We will render reCAPTCHA after the page is loaded,
    // because we want to bind our own submit methods.
    window.addEventListener('load', this.onLoad);
  }

  // Runs once the form is submitted.
  onRecaptcha = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    const { grecaptcha } = window;
    grecaptcha.execute();
  };

  // Real submit function.
  onSubmit = (token) => {
    // I'm not sure what token could be if recaptcha fails.
    // In my case it seems successful and returns a long string.
    console.log(token);

    // Your real action goes below...
  };

  onLoad = () => {
    // Now we define our reCAPTCHA
    if (window.grecaptcha) {
      const { grecaptcha } = window;
      grecaptcha.render('recaptcha', { // div#recaptcha
        sitekey  : '',
        size     : 'invisible',
        callback : this.onSubmit
      });
    }
  };

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <Helmet>
          <script
            src="https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api.js?onload=onloadCallback&render=explicit"
            async
            defer
          />
        </Helmet>
        <form onSubmit={this.onRecaptcha}>
          <div id="recaptcha" />
          <button type="submit">Submit</button>
        </form>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default YourComponent;
```

Comment: I've figured out that it's much easier with [scriptjs](https://github.com/ded/script.js) library. I'll pass an example if you wish.